# "Unable to open this helper application" after Sign In to Windows Azure on Visual Studio Server Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, azure, oauth-2.0, server-explorer, microsoft-account

I installed Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate version 12.0.30110.00 Update 1 on Windows 8.1 Enterprise. Then I installed the Windows Azure SDK 2.2.

I open VS, go to Server Explorer -> Windows Azure -> Connect to Windows Azure...

I insert the Microsoft Account, click Ok and this is what I get:

```
Unable to open this helper application for urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob?code=...
The protocol specified in this address is not valid. 
Make sure the address is correct, and try again.
```

I don't see my subscriptions. 
If I go to the Windows Azure portal (https://manage.windowsazure.com/) with IE 11, I see all my Subscriptions.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem. From my investigation it seems to me that the problem is that the "urn" protocol is associated in windows to Google Chrome but I can't figure out how to remove this association ... I guess it is in the registry